# Composition of Joint Distributions in TensorFlow Probability

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I am new to probabilistic programming and TFP. I am trying to use it for probabilistic graphical modelling, which appeals to me for its flexibility in breaking down complex models into simpler piecewise explanations. However I am having difficulty in defining higher level models which are probabilistically related to variables defined by lower level models.

Suppose I define the following distribution for a random variable `theta_1` based on explanatory variables `x_1, x_2` and likewise for `theta_2` based on `x_3, x_4`:

```py
theta_1_model = tfd.JointDistributionSequential(
    [
        tfd.Normal(0, 1, name='x_1'),
        tfd.Normal(0, 1, name='x_2'),
        lambda x_2, x_1: tfd.Normal(x_1, tf.exp(x_2), name='theta_1')
    ]
)
theta_2_model = tfd.JointDistributionSequential(
    [
        tfd.Normal(0, 1, name='x_3'),
        tfd.Normal(0, 1, name='x_4'),
        lambda x_4, x_3: tfd.Normal(x_3, tf.exp(x_4), name='theta_2')
    ]
)
```

I would then like to define models which rely on `theta_1` and `theta_2` as explanatory variables. For example suppose I would like to model a random variable `y` which is normally distributed about the difference between `theta_1` and `theta_2`. Given that `theta_1_model` and `theta_2_model` are themselves distributions (for dim-3 random variables) it seems like I should be able to use them within a JointDistributionSequential definition for `y` along the lines of:

```py
y_model = tfd.JointDistributionSequential(
    [
        theta_1_model,
        theta_2_model,
        lambda t_2_m, t_1_m: tfd.Normal(t_1_m[...,2]-t_2_m[...,2], 1, name='y')
    ]
)
```

where here I have attempted to use [..., 2] indexing to reference the theta component within the dim-3 distributions. This does not work however. **It is in specifying the relationship between new variables in the higher-level model and individual variables already defined in the lower level models that I am having difficulty**.

I could of course define the full model for `y` in one big `JointDistributionSequential` definition. However for more complicated applications where I'd like to reuse the lower level components this is infeasible.

There has recently been a white-paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.11819.pdf) published entitled 'Joint Distributions for TensorFlow Probability' with a 'Composition of Joint Distributions' section. This section suggests that joint distributions can in principle be combined in the way I'm suggesting, but doesn't show how the relationships between new variables in the higher-level model and variables already defined in the lower level models may be specified.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think your code will work with a small change. You are using `t_1_m[...,2]` but `t_1_m` is not a `Tensor` -- as a sample from a JDSequential, it's a python list of `Tensor`s. I tried it, replacing this with `t_1_m[2]` (sim'ly for the other one) and I was able to sample from the nested model and compute log probs.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Could've sworn I'd tried this but clearly not properly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work when the joint distribution we're trying to reference already has multiple levels of variables. For example suppose I successfully define ```y_model``` as above with your correction. If I then want to define a further distribution with ```y_model``` as an explanatory variable, I can not seem to access ```x_1``` from ```y_model``` as ```y_model[0][0]``` as we might expect (get an AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'sample'). Is this a known limitation or am I not quite doing it correctly again?

Comment: sounds like possibly a bug. can you file an issue on https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues with a repro example?

Comment: @ChrisSuter, when I tried your suggestion I got this error `TypeError: 'generator' object does not support item assignment`. Using TFP '0.9.0'.

Comment: @Maturin, I also got that error when trying to print the resultant ```y_model``` (the error seems to be in the ```__repr__()``` method). However I believe the resultant ```y_model``` is functional besides that. For example you can sample it etc.